# why "this" points to class rather than class object?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, events, this

Suppose i have 2 WinForms: f1 of class Form1, and f2 of class Form2. What i want to do is: by clicking button1 on f1, application will dispose f1 and run f2. And here is the code:

```
//Form1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent;
  }
  public delegate void EH_ChangeForm(object sender, EventArgs e);
  //this defines an event
  public static event EH_ChangeForm ChangeForm;
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //this raises the event
    ChangeForm(this, new EventArgs()); //  NRC happens here!!! Zzz~
  }
}

//Program
static class Program
{
  static Form1 f1;
  static Form2 f2;

  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    f1 = new Form1();
    f2 = new Form2();
    Application.Run(f1);
    //this subscribers to the event
    Form1.ChangeForm += Form1_ChangeForm;
  }

  static void Form1_ChangeForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    f1.Dispose();
    Application.Run(f2);
  }
```

}

The ***problem*** is: by clicking button1, program get suck when it tries to raise the event (line "ChangeForm(this, new EventArgs());"). NullReferenceException happens, "this" points to Form1 rather than f1.

***More generally***, how should i use events among classes? i.e., how should a class object subscribes to an event raised by another class object?

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about disposing at all, nor should you be using `Application.Run` to open a form, there are `Show` and `ShowDialog` to do that

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "this" points to Form1 rather than f1."

Comment: It's also not clear why you've chosen to create your own delegate type with exactly the same signature as `EventHandler`...

Comment: `this` represents the current instance. All of this would be a lot more easily debugged if you didn't mix partial classes with static classes, static events and explicit disposing at random places. What causes the NRE?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: what i want to transfer is an object, but "this" points to class, rather than object.   This program is just a test, to make it easy, i just did not define any special delegate.

Comment: It's not possible for `this` to reference anything other than an object.

Comment: @ Jeroen Vannevel :  What causes the NRE?     -- Well,,, the problem is : "this" points to Form1 (the class), but what i imagined is to point to f1 (the object).

Comment: Considering there's no method called `SeetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` on the class Application, are you sure that the rest of the code is correct? Why is there a b in the middle of the code? `this` cannot be a reference to Form1, as Matthew states. Depending on how you create your button, the click event handler should be contained in the actual instance of Form1.

Comment: "this" DOES point to f1. It is the event that is null.

Comment: @ Patrick： Sorry for mistyping.  The click is ok, NRC happens on the line inside it.

Comment: @ Dennis_E: Sorry, but what do you mean by "It is the event that is null" ?

Comment: @ Matthew Watson: Thanks, but NRC does happen on the line inside click.  What's wrong?

Comment: The event `ChangeForm` is not set to anything. The code you have does not get past `Application.Run` and thus does not register any event handlers to the static event `ChangeForm`, hence it is null.

Comment: @CharllyChen I mean the event `ChangeForm` is null. The line `Form1.ChangeForm += Form1_ChangeForm;` has not been executed, because `Application.Run` has not returned yet.

Comment: @ Patrick:Thanks.  Is that not a way to raise an event? How should i do then?

Comment: @ Dennis_E: Thanks, but how should i fix my program?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to raise an event, but when it's null, you will get a NRE. The answer by IVAAAN123 says you need to swap those 2 lines.

Comment: Because you are still inside the method `Application.Run(...)` the next line (`Form1.ChangeForm += Form1_ChangeForm;`) has not executed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get a `NullReferenceException` is because there is no event handler registered to your `Form1.ChangeForm`, because Application.Run waits for the instance f1 to stop receiving messages.

You need to swap the two lines in your Main method, like this:

```
 Form1.ChangeForm += Form1_ChangeForm;
 Application.Run(f1);
```

Always try to register event handlers "as fast as possible" so that you don't execute something and expect an event to be carried out when there is noone listening.

Also, when writing event invocators, try to use the pattern where you cache the event and then invoke it

```
private void FireChangeForm() {
    var handler = ChangeForm;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

So you avoid any race conditions as well. Please read the blog post [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) by Eric Lippert on why you should to this.